# Amazon S3 Bucket Policy Issue with Nodejs multer-s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, multer, multer-s3

I've created an api to upload image to amazon s3 bucket with nodejs, multer, and multer-s3 .
Its working fine in development returning me a response of image URL which is downloadable and accessible but when I host my node app on Aws Lambda (API GATEWAY) the API returns me the same response with the image URL but this time when I open the downloaded image it shows me **INVALID FILE FORMATTED**

Here is my Code

```
    const uploadImage = async (req,res) => {
  let myFile = req.file.originalname.split(".")
    const fileType = myFile[myFile.length - 1]

    const params = {
        Bucket: 'test-bucket2601',
        Key: `${Date.now()}.${fileType}`,
        Body: req.file.buffer
    }

  s3.upload(params, (error, data) => {
        if(error){
            res.status(500).send(error)
        }
        res.json({data})
        
    })

    
}
```

Route of middleware

```
routes.route('/upload').post(upload,uploadImage);
```

in post method the first argument is upload middleware

Middleware Code:

```
    const s3 = new aws.S3({
    credentials: {
    accessKeyId: awsKeys?.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: awsKeys?.secretAccessKey 
    }
   });

   const storage = multer.memoryStorage({
     destination: function(req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, '')
     }})

    const upload = multer({storage}).single('imageUrl')
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your posting.
Please attach responseType property with "arraybuffer" to request headers.
It will work.
Thank you.